# how to give path of feature file in runner file

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

in src/test/featurefile, i have created two folder US-Portals and Canada-Portals, these two folders contains multiple feature files.
how can i provide path in runner file for feature file for both portals?

```
features = { "src/test/featurefile/" }, 
plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
    "junit:target/cucumber-junit-report/allcukes.xml", "json:target/cucumber-report.json",
    "json:target/cucumber.json", "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json" },

tags = { "@SaveContract_US_BMW, @SaveContract_Canada_BMW" }
```

Answer (score 3):

To execute all feature files in the folder src/test/featurefile ( include both US-Portals and Canada-Portals folders)

```
features={"src/test/featurefile"}
```

To execute all feature files in the folder US-Portals

```
features =  { "src/test/featurefile/US-Portals"}
```

To execute all feature files in the folder Canada-Portals

```
features =  { "src/test/featurefile/Canada-Portals"}
```

To execute a single feature file in  US-Portals folder (eg. sample1.feature)

```
features =  { "src/test/featurefile/US-Portals/sample1.feature"}
```

To execute a single feature file in  US-Canada folder (eg. sample1.feature)

```
features =  { "src/test/featurefile/US-Canada/sample1.feature"}
```

No need to pass tags value if you want to execute all files. if you pass it, it will execute only the scenario/feature with that tag.  All other scnenarios/features are skipped.

Note: Feature file name and tag names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the path where all features reside like this:

```
features = {"classpath:demo_features"}
```